# How to get the bounds of ClusteredMapView

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using this plugin https://github.com/novalabio/react-native-maps-super-cluster. It says in the docs that use this plugin https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps . And in this plugin (react-native-maps) there is a function to get the bounds i see it in the docs (getMapBoundaries) . My question is if i can access that function using the clustering plugin. Here is my code:

```
renderCluster = (cluster, onPress) => {
    const pointCount = cluster.pointCount,
      coordinate = cluster.coordinate,
      clusterId = cluster.clusterId

    const clusteringEngine = this.map.getClusteringEngine(),
      clusteredPoints = clusteringEngine.getLeaves(clusterId, 100)

      let map = this.map.getMapRef()
      console.log(9,map.props.onRegionChangeComplete())

      const bgColor = ()=>{
       if(pointCount<10)
       return 'purple';
       if(pointCount<99)
       return 'green';
       if(pointCount<999)
       return 'red';
       return 'blue';
      };
      const radio = String(pointCount).length * 12 + 5; 

    return (

      <Marker coordinate={coordinate} onPress={onPress}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: bgColor(), width: radio, height: radio,  borderRadius: radio/2, padding: 4, alignItems: "center", justifyContent:"center", borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#FFF"}}>

        <Text style={{color: "#FFF", fontSize: 12, fontWeight: "400"}}>
            {pointCount}
          </Text>

        </View>
      </Marker>
    )
  }

  renderMarker = (data) => <Marker image={CONFIG.info.marker} key={data.id || Math.random()} coordinate={data.location} />


  render() {
    return (

      <ClusteredMapView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        data={this.state.data}
        initialRegion={INIT_REGION}
        ref={(r) => { this.map = r }}
        renderMarker={this.renderMarker}
        renderCluster={this.renderCluster} />

    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const mapBoundaries = this.map.getMapRef().getMapBoundaries();
```